# MSSQL User Function, OPENQUERY, dynamic sql

Tags: sql-server, function, select, openquery

I'm having a very hard time to built user function, I would like get a value from the openquery,
I need to pass one parameter into this function, I'm trying to debug this in the editor,
@catalog is my passing parameter

```
declare @val decimal(18, 3), @catalog varchar(50);
set @catalog = '08553101';

select @val = (STPRS/PEINH) from openquery([NEWDB], 'select STPRS, PEINH from DATA.CATALOGS where CATALOG = ''' + @catalog + '''  ')
return @val;
```

but getting error "SQL Server Database Error: Incorrect syntax near '+'."
Not sure how to build Openquery.
Please advice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `OPENQUERY()` does not support expression as input. For your requirement, you need to make the entire query dynamic

Answer (score 0):

I would follow Erlang Sommarskog's advice in section 6.2 of his article at
http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html. He pulls no punches when it comes to providing massive amounts of information and important details that are otherwise hard to find or figure out.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is not helping as exec sp_executesql can't be used with return, and I need to build user function with it.